# Why does trying to open a sub-shell in a for loop give a syntax error at done?

Tags: bash, error-handling

If I execute this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
j=0
for(( i=1;i<(j);i++ ))
do
  echo j
done
```

I get:

```
./test: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./test: line 6: `done'
```

I know that the problem are the extra parenthesis at `(j)`, but I would like to understand why it detects the error at line 6, not 3. What is the logic here?

Comment: It seems that the `<(` is the issue. Adding a space in between will remove the error. I wonder if the parser gets confused about a process substitution inside an arithmetic expression?

Comment: FWIW your code appears to execute without error in bash 4.4.12 but not in bash 4.3.48